# LDAP C++ how do I check that a user has a valid password?

Tags: c++, ldap, openldap

I am trying to figure out how to check if a user has a valid password with LDAP c++ code.  This seems maddeningly difficult for what seems to be it's intended purpose.

The only working example code I could find was ldapsearch.  I can log in as the default user and search for the user:

```
ldapsearch -x -D "cn=ldap,cn=Users,dc=company,dc=local" -W -H ldap://localhost:389 -b "ou=company_account,dc=company,dc=local"  -s sub 'uid=my_id'
```

This seems to correspond to this code (note: lots of error checking removed)

```
LDAP *ld = NULL;
string sHostIP = session.ini["ldap_host"];
string  sPort   = session.ini["ldap_port"];
string  sURL    = sHostIP+":"+sPort;
ldap_initialize( &ld, sURL.c_str() );

int iVersion = LDAP_VERSION3;
ldap_set_option( ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &iVersion );

string sLDAPPW = session.ini["ldap_server_pw"];
struct berval pServerPassword = { 0, NULL };
pServerPassword.bv_val = ber_strdup( &sLDAPPW[0] );
pServerPassword.bv_len = strlen( pServerPassword.bv_val );

//can't bind without this code block, but what does it even do?
int iMsgid;
int nsctrls = 0;
LDAPControl c;
c.ldctl_oid = LDAP_CONTROL_PASSWORDPOLICYREQUEST;
c.ldctl_value.bv_val = NULL;
c.ldctl_value.bv_len = 0;
c.ldctl_iscritical = 0;
LDAPControl sctrl[3];
sctrl[nsctrls] = c;
LDAPControl *sctrls[4];
sctrls[nsctrls] = &sctrl[nsctrls];
sctrls[++nsctrls] = NULL;
LDAPControl **sctrlsp = NULL;
if ( nsctrls )
{
    sctrlsp = sctrls;
}

KString sBindDN = session.ini["ldap_bind_dn"];
ldap_sasl_bind( ld, sBindDN.c_str(), LDAP_SASL_SIMPLE, &pServerPassword,sctrlsp, NULL, &iMsgid );
```

This is where, if we kept the hashed userPassword value I could search for a uid and userPassword combination.  but since my company doesn't keep userPassword, that won't work.

I'm told that the other way to check the password is to bind as the user with the user password.  But I need to use a different DN so I'm binding as user?  Or I log in as the admin first then do a second bind as the user?  And apparently this code is depreciated, but every non-depreciated example code I try to build crashes?  Is there something I'm missing?  Is there a good working example I use to authenticate users?  I know apache can authenticate off of this LDAP server, but I don't know how.

Apache ldap.conf info here:

```
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://localhost:389/ou=company_account,dc=company,dc=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
AuthLDAPBindDN  "cn=ldap,cn=Users,dc=company,dc=local"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "removed"
```

Comment: Yes, you'll need to change the BindDN and the BindPassword to match that user. After that when you bind and if it's successful then that means user has entered correct password.

Comment: @KULKING  But what do we need to change the bind DN to, is the real question.  I can't find a clear working answer for this.  I've tried adding lots of variations on ',uid=username', 'sAMAccountName=username', etc.  If you can tell me what I need to add to the bind DN I will give you the bounty.

Comment: You use the DN of the user that you found with the search. That's what you were looking for.

Comment: okay, I see.  it looks like another thing I missed is that ldap search separates the base DN and the bind DN, and I was accidentally changing the baseDN instead of the bind dn. This ldap command works:  ldapsearch -x -D "CN=my name,OU=company-Users,OU=Users,OU=User Account,OU=company_account,DC=tpnyc,DC=local" -W -H ldap://localhost:389 -b "ou=company_account,dc=company,dc=local"  -s sub 'uid=myid'

Answer (score 1):

you need just to perform ldap bind or sasl_bind

```
void TLDAP::sasl_simple_bind(const std::string & ldapDn, const std::string & ldapPw)
{
    struct berval c_passwd = { 0, 0 };
    c_passwd.bv_val = const_cast<char*>(ldapPw.c_str());
    c_passwd.bv_len = ldapPw.size();
    Check(ldap_sasl_bind_s(l.get(), ldapDn.c_str(), LDAP_SASL_SIMPLE, &c_passwd, NULL, NULL, NULL));
}

void TLDAP::simple_bind(const std::string & ldapDn, const std::string & ldapPw)
{
    Check(ldap_simple_bind_s(l.get(), ldapDn.c_str(), ldapPw.c_str()));            
}
```

ldap_simple_bind for non-encrypted connection, sasl_bind for encrypted

invocation example:

```
TLDAP::sasl_simple_bind("andrey@mydomain.local", "1234asdf%^^&");
```

function Check just checks the return value and throws exception

Comment: This answer may crash, depending on the server you are connecting to, because your bind is missing the sctrlsp.  The biggest issue is non binding the user DN, I already have code for that in my question. The issue is searching for the DN to bind to without crashing or getting an error from the server. I'll add my own answer if I ever figured it out...